# Member method overloading in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, overloading

Is it even possible to overload member methods? like:

```
create or replace type triangle as object(
side_1 number,
side_2 number,
side_3 number,
member function perimeter return number);

create or replace type body triangle as
member function perimeter return number is
begin
  return self.side_1 + self.side_2 + self.side_3;
  end;
end;
```

So yes, how can I overload `perimeter` function. Can anyone give any example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28371/adobjbas.htm#i471260

Comment: Actually that's completely not what I was looking for.